# C# draw circle around label

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I draw a circle around a label?

Right now I've tried this:

```
public void drawUseCase(int width, int height, UseCase useCase)
{
    Label lbUseCase = new Label();
    Graphics g = lbUseCase.CreateGraphics();
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    g.DrawEllipse(p, width, height, 200, 200);
    lbUseCase.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(width, height);
    lbUseCase.Text = useCase.name;
    mainPanel.Controls.Add(lbUseCase);
}
```

But that's not working. Any ideas?

It's in winforms. With 'it's not working' I mean that only the label shows up but no circle or what so ever.

Comment: This is Windows Phone 7? 8, 10? ASP.NET, MVC? Forms?

Comment: "But that's not working " what's not working?  How it's not working?  What unexpected thing your are seeing?  Error? Crash ?

Comment: @CasparKleijne Yes. That defienitevly is MVC... This code indicates clearly that it's WinForms...

Comment: We all know Caspar is just fishing to show OP that he misses critical information to diagnose the issue. Asking what framework they are using is just to show how much is missing.

Comment: write the code inside the Form_paint event. That must work

Comment: your label is almost certainly overwriting your ellipse.

Comment: You are missing the whole concept of how drawing occurs in winforms. You can simply create `UserControl` where you combine controls (is there one to draw lines in winforms?) to have appearance you want or create custom control (e.g. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20997144/1997232)) which draw circle around in `Paint` event.

Comment: CreateGraphics() is a **temporary** drawing surface; it will get erased when the form/controls refresh themselves.  The Paint() event of _something_ is the better approach; use the `e.Graphics` supplied within it.  A control can't draw outside of its rectangular bounds, though...so if you want the circle "around" the Label it would have to drawn in the Paint() event of the **Labels Container**.

Comment: Refer this MSDN document. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h34kh0x2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [How can I treat the circle as a control after drawing it? - Moving and selecting shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345828/how-can-i-treat-the-circle-as-a-control-after-drawing-it-moving-and-selecting)

Comment: You also can save your drawing: [How to save shapes which I draw on a Panel as binary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40575797/3110834)
`

Comment: Also here is another example: [How to drag and move shapes in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38749134/3110834)

Comment: Forget about `Label` and use a solution like above examples. You will find theme useful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label Label = new Label();
    Label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 50);
    Label.Width = 50;
    Label.Height = 50;
    Label.Name = "lblTest";
    Label.Text = "test";
    this.Controls.Add(Label);
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var lbl = this.Controls.Find("lblTest",true); // find label with name

    foreach (var item in lbl) 
    // there can be multiple lblTest with same name so I used foreach (this is optional btw you can remove it)
    {
        Label tempLabel = item as Label;
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        System.Drawing.Pen myPen = new Pen(myBrush, 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(tempLabel.Location.X - (tempLabel.Width / 2),
        tempLabel.Location.Y - (tempLabel.Height / 2)  , tempLabel.Width + 40, tempLabel.Height + 40));
        myBrush.Dispose();
        myPen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Result:** 
[image]

Hope helps.

Comment: Don't forget disposing your brushes (`using`!)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks, updated :)

Comment: Why the animation? Couldn't you just do a screenshot?

Comment: Is it relevant with the code? What is the harm? @krlzlx

Comment: I'm sorry, I found it a little disturbing while reading. Plus the animation doesn't bring any value added.

Comment: Animated gif is always cool. No matter what context.

Comment: Animated gif = proof also. We can see build and run.