# VB.Net - Change the Panel's Border color

Tags: vb.net, colors, border, panel

I searched in stack **overflow** something like this "How to change Panel's border color vb.net" and no results found so, I removed the vb.net and just typed like that and I found results but it is for C# only and I don't C# that much better and maybe I thought I could translate but I just thought translating will not be **100% Accurate** so, that's why I made this question. Please help me how do I change the Panel's border Color in **VB.Net** I've set the BorderStyle FixedSingle in properties but there is still nothing I can do to change the Panel's border color. Please help and tell me how to change the Panel's border color or we can't do it from properties and we can do it by coding then at least please give me the code.

Comment: You don't change the border colour. If you set the `BorderStyle` to `FixedSingle` then you live with what you get. The alternative is to draw a border yourself using GDI+, probably calling `Graphics.DrawRectangle` in the `Paint` event handler or in the `OnPaint` method of a custom control. We don't just give you the code here at SO. It's up to you to do the research and make an attempt, then post a question if you encounter a specific issue. That you don't know how is a reason to find out how, not to give up and expect us to tell you how. If you try and fail, then we can talk again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already mentioned, there's a [c# version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996104/how-to-change-panel-border-color) with multiple answers.

Here's a short summary of the answers:

**Possibility 1**

The simplest and codeless way is as follows:

- Set the `BackColor` of `Panel1` to the desired bordercolor
- Set the `Padding` of `Panel1` to the desired border-thickness (e.g. `2;2;2;2`)
- Create a `Panel2` inside `Panel1` and set the `Dock`-property to `Fill`
- Set the `BackColor`of `Panel2` to the desired background color

Caveat: *Transparent background can not be used.*

**Possibility 2**

Draw a Border inside the `Paint` event-handler.

(Translated to VB.NET from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53283185/2967965).)

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, Panel1.ClientRectangle, Color.DarkBlue, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
End Sub
```

**Possibility 3**

Create your own `Panel`-class and draw the border in the client area.

(Translated to VB.NET from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20997144/2967965).)

```
<System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")>
Public Class MyPanel
    Inherits Panel

    Public Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Using brush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(BackColor)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle)
        End Using

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Yellow, 0, 0, ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1)
    End Sub
End Class
```